# difference between function context (this) in node.js and browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, this

I am aware of how "this" works in a browser context , and how its value changes in different scenarios  like when using arrow functions how the function is invoked.

I printed out "this" in different scenarios for node js (express js, to be more specific), and it is containing a  lot more data - including path names etc

My question is :
1. are the rules concerning 'this' exactly the same for node.js ?
2. could any one explain the node.js 'this' object properties or point me to a simple article.

Thank you!

Comment: Yes. NodeJS is just a runtime for JavaScript, all of JavaScript's rules apply exactly the same...

Comment: *"could any one explain the node.js 'this' object properties or point me to a simple article."* I hate to say it, but this translates to "can someone write google it for me and write up a summary?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no different rules for `this` in a browser vs. node.js.  The rules are set by the ECMAScript standards and both the browser's Javascript implementation and the one in node.js follow the same ECMAScript standards.

What you are probably looking at is a "default" value for `this` in some particular context.  In a browser, you are probably looking at a default value for `this` that may be the `window` object.  In node.js, if you see filenames, you may be looking at a module handle as the default value for `this` or the `global` object.

To help you more specifically, we would need to see the code around where you were examining the value of `this` in each environment and also know whether you were running in strict mode or not.

In most cases, `this` is not used with just a default value, but rather a specific object that the `this` value is set to.  For example, if you are calling something like:

```
obj.method();
```

Then, inside the implementation of `method`, the Javascript interpreter will set the value of `this` to `obj`.  This is a part of the object oriented nature of Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

This `this` object is whatever the `global` object is in that context. In node that is the `process` object.

Comment: maybe you mean ```global``` object

Answer (score 1):

I observed a difference between `this` in a module when running on node (tests) and a browser (production).

in tests:

the following type of code worked fine when run by tests:

```
export function A()
{
}

export function B()
{
  // NOTE: DON'T DO THIS. prepending "this." is not needed and might break.
  this.A();
}
```

But on production it would throw:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'A' of undefined
```

However this is **NOT** a difference between node + browser/webview but rather a difference between production code (production build of bundle.js via webpack v4) and code running in tests.

With a debug build of bundle.js `this` would point to the module (so an object containing exported module symbols)
eg:

```
{
  A : [Function: A]
  B : [Function: B]
}
```

Whereas in a release build of bundle.js `this` returns `undefined`

This difference of behaviour is caused by webpacks [`concatenateModules`](https://v4.webpack.js.org/configuration/optimization/#optimizationconcatenatemodules) optimization.